# SwiftyJSON - expression is ambiguous

Tags: ios, swift, swifty-json

I try to parse JSON using SwiftyJSON but I face a problem.

I use tutorial from [here](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/read/7/3/parsing-json-nsdata-and-swiftyjson)

Here is my code

```
var JSONStorage : [Article?]?
var objects = [[String: String]]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let number = arc4random_uniform(1000)
    let urlString = "http://78.27.190.58:3200/api/get_article/17?\(number)"

    if let url = NSURL(string: urlString) {
        if let data = try? NSData(contentsOfURL: url, options: []) {
            let json = JSON(data: data)

            for element in json["article"].arrayValue {

                let id = Int(element["id"].stringValue)
                let title = element["title"].stringValue
                let subtitle = element["subtitle"].stringValue
                let body = element["body"].stringValue
                let img = element["images"]["main"].rawValue
                let obj = ["id": id, "title": title, "subtitle": subtitle, "body": body, "img": img]


                objects.append(obj)

            }

        }
    }

}
```

here is the error I got

[image]

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `objects` is of type `[[String:String]]`, an array of dictionaries. These dictionaries are typed `String` for the key and `String` for the value.

But you add to this array a dictionary containing different types of values: `String`s with your `.stringValue` objects, and a `.rawValue` one which must be of type NSData I presume.

A solution could be to type your dictionary `[String:AnyObject]` (and thus your array `[[String:AnyObject]]`) and to typecast on the other side when retrieving the values.

By the way, the compiler says "expression is ambiguous" because it failed at inferring the type of the array (and now we know why).

*Note that it's not the most efficient when parsing JSON. A better way would be to create objects from your data: classes or structs. You could have a struct `Article` to hold each `element` values for example, like you showed in another question.*

Answer (score 0):

Arrays or Dictionaries in swift can not be heterogeneous. If you look at your code you want to put one int and four strings as values of obj.

This will work:

```
for element in json["article"].arrayValue {

            let id = element["id"].stringValue // must be string to put it in obj
            let title = element["title"].stringValue
            let subtitle = element["subtitle"].stringValue
            let body = element["body"].stringValue
            let img = element["images"]["main"].rawValue
            let obj: [String: String] = ["id": id, "title": title, "subtitle": subtitle, "body": body, "img": img]


            objects.append(obj)

        }
```